# Add all files in git

Tags: git, msysgit, git-add

I have this git status:

```
User#/d/Work/Project/Module1/NV/build (master)$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   ../../Module1/CMakeLists.txt
#       modified:   ../../Module1/Container.cpp
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How can I add the 2 files? `git add -A` doesn't work?
I know it's possible to use the option `git add ../../.` for obvious reasons.

I know it's possible to add the files with a `git add` option but i can't remember it and I don't find it. I use `git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1`.

Comment: You are in subdirectory. Why you can't do just this command? cd ../.. && git add .

Comment: > no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "**git commit -a**")?

Comment: @cooperok I already said that `git add ../../.` is not an option.

Comment: @Ajedi34 Did you read my question? I already sad that I tried `git add -A .`, and it does not work. I thought that it is obvious that `git add .` does not work. And I want to add the files not to commit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run `git add -A` from a subdirectory, my version of git (1.8.3.3) gives me this warning:

> warning: The behavior of 'git add --all (or -A)' with no path argument
>   from a subdirectory of the tree will change in Git 2.0 and should not
>   be used anymore. To add content for the whole tree, run:
>
> git add --all :/   (or git add -A :/)
>
> To restrict the command to the current directory, run:
>
> git add --all .   (or git add -A .)
>
> With the current Git version, the command is restricted to the current
>   directory.

So what you're probably looking for is `git add -A :/`. You can easily create an alias for this with `git config --global alias.addall 'add -A :/'`.

Answer (score 1):

The `rev-parse` command can be used to find the root of your git project, you could then pass that into the `git add` command, like so:

```
git add $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

Comment: The use of the `$()` subshell works for me, within Bash.  I'm not sure about what msysgit gives you

Comment: Works in `msysgit` as well